# OffsetDateTime parse ignores seconds when hours,minutes and seconds are zero

Tags: java

While parsing OffsetDateTime with a DateFormatter pattern and given date with hours,minutes and seconds are 0. The seconds are being ignored in the output. But how can we get the values with 0 seconds as well.

```
String  date  ="2018-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00";
String  DATEFORMATTER= "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX";
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(date,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATEFORMATTER)));
```

Actual Output :2018-12-30T00:00Z

Expected Output : 2018-12-30T00:00:00Z

Comment: You aren't providing any _output_ format.

Comment: The Output format is in the Expected output yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'